# How to resolve The type 'xxx' exists both in '[website root]' and 'App_Code' from a MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, duplicates

I have created a custom identity, principal and membership provider and accessing them through a UserContext class (all sitting in App_code):

```
public static class UserContext
{
    public static CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get
        {
            return (CustomPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;
        }
    }

    public static CustomIdentity Identity 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return (CustomIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity; 
        } 
    }
}
```

From a controller class, I can do:

```
string userName = UserContext.Identity.Name;
```

However when doing the following from a view:

```
 @Html.Encode(UserContext.Identity.Name)
```

I get the following error at run time:

> The type 'Website.Infrastructure.UserContext' exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\533b7079\25c5a39c\assembly\dl3\13397e32\308e247b_c8efce01\Website.DLL'
>   and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\533b7079\25c5a39c\App_Code.-ze7s5wd.dll'

I have cleared out the temp/cache IISExpress folders, etc., [ensured that I'm using System.Web v4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284603/the-type-xxx-exists-in-both-argh), and have tried with adding the `using [namespace]` at the top of the shared layout view and in the relevant view's Web.config section.

Looking at the view, I'm seeing a compile error (suggestion?) under

```
UserContext
```

> The type 'xxx' exists both in '[website root]' and 'App_Code' from a
>   MVC view

Suggestions?

Comment: App_code is a legacy holdover from older versions of asp.net move your code into a class library

Comment: or even just move the class files to a different, non-ASP.NET special folder, like ~/Library/

Comment: @MikeBeeler - I removed the classes from App_Code, and created a new class library called `Website.Infrastructure`, and put them all in there.  Same issue.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is your library code in a utility class]

Works fine. I notice that in your original description you add references to the views web.config. This is not correct and the views web.config <> to the web.config for the application.

- add a reference to the utility project to the main web site
- Build.

In your case take the references out of everywhere else in any of the other config files. I can make the project available to you if you like

Comment: As this did help, I am marking it as the solution.  However I did have a few more issues that were manifested by an A cannot be cast to B exception (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119398/a-cannot-be-cast-to-b-exception).  I still had the old code in my App_Code folder.  Even though I had them set to *Exclude from project* they were for some reason causing this issue.  Deleted them, and the `Infrastructure` project now works fine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment but I don't have enough points to comment so giving answer to this.

try to use full qualified class name like

> **Namespace.UserContext**

, this might solve the conflict.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however this was also attempted, as you can see from the error, with the fully-qualified class name: `Website.Infrastructure.UserContext`.